# XAML Islands - build with higher Target Platform Version

Tags: c++, xaml, msbuild, windows-runtime, winui-3

I would like to compile project described here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/host-custom-uwp-controls-in-mfc-mdi-project-using-xaml-islands/ba-p/1130087

using Target Platform Version >= 10.0.19041.0

There is  an error shown:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2259   'winrt::MyApp::implementation::XamlMetaDataProvider': cannot instantiate abstract class (compiling source file App.cpp) MyApp   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory  1915

Sources for the project are there: https://github.com/freistli/ModernizeApp/tree/master/MFC/MFCAppWinUI

Comment: It turned out the body of the file app.base.h must be changed to use winrt::com_ptr rather than std pointer types.
The best approach hovewer would be not to use pointer here at all. The ready solution (body of app.base.h) is at :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp

Answer (score 0):

Ensure SDK Version MFCAPP is greater than or equal to MyApp. And "Target Platform" and "Target min Platform" of MyApp is Same and and greater than 18362